# Configure WebApps Using slf4j in eclipse and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, slf4j, eclipse-wtp

I'm developing a web application using eclipse and maven. For testing, I'm using WTP to deploy and run app using tomcat 8. In the code I'm using slf4j for logging and slf4j-jdk for the logging implementation. The problem is it seems wtp is ignoring logging.properties that I put on src/resources. When I test deploying by exporting the project as war file, it reads correctly.

How to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On eclipse tomcat configuration click "Open Launch Configuration" add this line in Arguments -> VM arguments:
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager

The logging.properties on classpath will be honored and read.